# Number of ways to distribute pencils

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can $20$ indistinguishable pencils be distributed among four children $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$?

What I tried is that we can distribute $A$ one pencil in $20$ ways and similarly number of ways of distribution are $20.19.18.18=116280$

But I am getting wrong answer. Please help. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: It looks like you intended to write $20 \cdot 19 \cdot 18 \cdot \color{red}{17} = 116280$, which is the number of ways of distributing four distinct pencils so that each student receives one pencil.  However, the pencils are indistinguishable, a student may not receive any pencils, and all $20$ pencils must be distributed.

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem.
Each combination can be represented as a string with 20 stars, separated by 3 bars, so the number of such solutions is identical to the number of strings, which is
$$
\binom{20+3}{3} = \binom{23}{3} = \binom{23}{20}
$$